# Decoding the following link

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been digging in some javascript api's lately and I found the following line:

```js
get_url_info: function($db_link) {
    var ldst_href;
    if ($db_link.data('ldst-href')) {
        ldst_href = $db_link.data('ldst-href');
    }
    else {
        ldst_href = $db_link.attr('href');
    }
    var matchs = ldst_href.match(/^http:\/\/([^\.]+)\..*playguide\/db\/(.*?)\/?(#.+)?$/);
    var subdomain = matchs[1];
    var path = matchs[2];
    if (!eorzeadb.dynamic_tooltip && eorzeadb.versions.data) {
        url = eorzeadb.cdn_prefix + 'pc/tooltip/' + eorzeadb.versions.data +
              '/' + subdomain + '/' + path + '.js';
    }
    else {
        url = ldst_href + '/jsonp/';
    }
    return {
        'url': url,
        'data_key': subdomain + '/' + path
    };
},
```

This result is supposed the return an array which I assume is contained in the link. I'm having a hard time decrypting the link tho. 
Does anybody have any experience with these kinds of links or a way that I could start out?

Comment: This is a regular expression, not a "link" (and neither an URI)

Comment: What is ldst_href?

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do. What does "decrypting the link" mean? If you just want to know what the resulting array contains, do `console.log(matchs)` and look in the console.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Match returns an array that has the recognized patterns that were set by the parameter (the regex)

var x = y.match(/aaa/g) would match all the strings that have aaa in them and return a bunch of aaa's in the array, as many as found.

Comment: Added the entire snippet, would like to know the results of the array to fill in the data that is required later

Answer (score 1):

http://regexr.com/
Here you can understand all the parts of the regex. Basically, is looking for a pattern like this:

```
http://(blablah).playguide/db/(OPTIONAL)(optional/)#(probably some id)
```

The result will be an array with the original link, followed by the domain, the first optional argument, and the hashtag, something like this

```
["http://(blablah).playguide/db/(OPTIONAL)(optional/)#(probably some id)", "(blablah)", "(OPTIONAL)(optional/)", "#(probably some id)"]
```

It will then use that information to build a different link